# Show that $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2\leq M^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f(z)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz_k$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ and $|f(z)|\leq M$:

I want to show that $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2\leq M^2$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Compute the average

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(re^{i\varphi})\rvert^2\,d\varphi$$

and let $r\nearrow 1$.

Comment: I got this: $1/2\pi \int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\phi})|^2d\phi=\Sigma_{0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2r^{2k}$ How do I proceed?

Comment: Let $r\nearrow 1$. You have a bound, so the limit ($\sum \lvert a_k\rvert^2$) is finite.

Comment: I think I get it: on the other hand $1/2\pi \int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\phi})|^2=1/2\pi \oint_{|z|=r}|f(z)|^2dz\leq M^2r$. Letting $r\to 1$ we obtain $\Sigma_0^{\infty}|a_k|^2\leq M^2 $ is this correct? @Daniel Fischer

Comment: You don't have an $r$ there, plain $\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(e^{i\varphi})\rvert^2\,d\varphi \leqslant \int_0^{2\pi} M^2\,d\varphi = 2\pi M^2$ (haven't divided the integral here). And $d\varphi = \frac{dz}{iz}$. But apart from that, yes, that's it.